# How to create/remove task and resource in project 2016 by using office.js?

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, ms-project

I'm developing a MS Project add-in by using office.js, is there any function or anyway that I can use to create/remove task and resource?
I only found functions about "set" and "get" task/resource in API reference document, but I found no functions about "create" and "delete".

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a link to the API ref pages that you were checking.

Comment: Here is the API ref document that I was checking- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview

Comment: This page, [JavaScript API for Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/project-add-ins-reference-overview), says "there's currently no JavaScript API designed specifically for interacting with Project." And none of the examples involve editing (or adding) tasks. Suggest building your add-in using c# or vb.net.

Comment: Oops, maybe I need to try c# or vba, thank you so much for your help.